# How to match records that meet multiple and indirect relationships in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, relationship

I Searched and found some similar cases but not exactly what I was looking for.

e.g. node "Players" have the following relations

```
Players -> Has_Racket 
Players -> Has_Balls

Balls -> Has_TennisBall
Balls -> Has_BasketBall
Balls -> Has_VolleyBall
Balls -> Has_PingPongBall
Balls -> ... ...
```

There is no direct relationship between Player and Balls. And this make it hard for me to query.

A player may not have a ball, a player may have a single type of ball, or a player may have multiple type of balls.

I want to find all players who have TennisBall and BasketBall but no VolleyBall. And I must use relationship  "Players -> Has_Balls".

Thanks.

Comment: Your data model is unclear. What are your [node labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels) and [relationship types](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-relationship-types)? And what properties do you have in your nodes and relationships? Also, are you allowed to modify your data model?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your model I would use the following query to get all players with a tennisBall and basketBall, but no VolleyBall

```
MATCH (p:Player)
WHERE (p)-[:Has_Balls]->()-[:Has_TennisBall]->()
AND (p)-[:Has_Balls]->()-[:Has_BasketBall]->()
AND NOT (p)-[:Has_Balls]->()-[:Has_VoleyBall]->()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply and that's helpful. But I had to admit I made a mistake in my first post. The actual and accurate situation is like this

```
Players -> Has_Racket 
Players -> Has_Balls

Balls -> Has_Types 

{"description": "Base_Ball", "value": "Base Ball"}
{"description": "Tennis_Ball", "value": "Tennis Ball"}
{"description": "Basket_Ball", "value": "Basket Ball"}
```

I need to query players who has base ball and tennis ball but no basket ball.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to switch the ball types without rewriting the query, I guess you could do something like this

```
// here in the WITH, but you could use parameters as well

WITH ['Base Ball','Tennis Ball'] AS shoulds,
     ['Basket Ball'] AS shouldnots

MATCH (p:Player)
WITH p,[(p)-[:Has_Balls]->()-[:Has_Types]->(type) | type.value] AS balltypes
WHERE NONE(b IN balltypes WHERE b IN shouldnots)
      AND ALL(b IN balltypes WHERE b IN shoulds)
RETURN p
```